# Capture or select picture and select area to crop to make it square

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, crop

I have a problem concerning capturing or selecting a profile picture in the app, **which should be square**. 
(When I'm talking about 'capturing the picture' in this post I always also mean selecting a picture from the gallery, this should work the same)

Until now I've just used the basic MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent action for capturing the picture and after that, I just crop it to make it square. This does work but it would be much better if the user could choose the area to crop himself after he has captured the picture.
When capturing a picture a preview is shown anyway where you can decide if you like the picture. It would be great if you could select the area to crop there (and not after having confirmed the preview).

Is there any source available that does this? I know I could do it myself, but I'd prefer the default camera app because then the user can choose every setting and effects.
I suppose it's not available in the android SDK (it is in iOS but in spite of my love to android it's very unlikely that useful basic things are available without a dozen additional libraries...)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=crop